# Behavior of static blocks with Abstract classes

Tags: java, abstract-class, static-block

Child Class:

```
public class ChildExtending extends ParentAbstract{

    public int childInt =111213;
    static{
        System.out.println("child static block executed");
    }

    public ChildExtending() {
        System.out.println("child const initialized");
    }
    public void MethodInChild(){
        System.out.println("MethodInChild called");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(ParentAbstract.parentInt);
        System.out.println(ChildExtending.parentInt);
    }
}
```

Abstract Class:

```
public abstract class ParentAbstract {
    public static int parentInt=80713; 
    static{
        System.out.println("parent static executed");
        parentInt=9;
    }

    public ParentAbstract(){
        System.out.println("parentAbstract initialized");
    }

    public void MethodInParent(){
        System.out.println("MethodInParent called");
    }

}
```

Main class:

```
public class MainForCheck {
    public static void main(String[] args){
    /*  ParentAbstract pa = new ParentAbstract(){

        };*/

    /*  ChildExtending ce = new ChildExtending();
        ce.childInt=5;*/

        /*ChildExtending ce = new ChildExtending();
        ce.childInt=5;
        ce.MethodInChild();
        System.out.println("pareny int is"+ce.parentInt);*/


        ChildExtending ce = new ChildExtending();
        ce.MethodInParent();

    }
}
```

**This gives me output:**

parent static executed
]

child static block executed

parentAbstract initialized

child const initialized

MethodInParent called

**Why is it not like this?**

parent static executed

parentAbstract initialized

child static block executed

child const initialized

MethodInParent called

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well first `ChildExtending` needs to be initialized (as a type). That will produce the output of

```
 parent static executed
 child static block executed
```

as per [section 12.4.2 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2).

Only once the type is initialized can the constructor be called, at which point you'll get the output of:

```
 parentAbstract initialized
 child const initialized
```

And once the object is constructed, you can call an instance method on it, with output of:

```
MethodInParent called
```

I think the piece you're missing is that the type has to be completely initialized before the constructor starts. The constructor call can't initialize *just* enough of the superclass to call its constructor, then initialize the subclass. Aside from anything else, if you call `getClass()` in the superclass constructor, that has to be a fully initialized class - which has to be the subclass, because that's what the object *is* an instance of.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever class loads first time its static blocks always get executed first. So here Its Parent and child's static block is executed then instance block or method executes